# What are the consequences of praying in the time of necessity for the Asr prayer

Tags: salat

What are the consequences of praying in the time of necessity for the Asr prayer?

What is the difference between whether someone has a valid reason or if one does not?

Comment: The consequence is that one will miss any rewards and in worst case would be regarded as a sinner.

Comment: @Medi1Saif that seems to be the case, but when I've looked online parts of that seem to be missing, or only cover when you have a valid reason. I'm looking for an authoritative source.